# How to use Date function in hibernate query language

Tags: hibernate

Hi trying to fetch the records from database based on the date wise,how can i achieve this
in database i have column like start_date with datatype datetime and in model class i have data member like

```
public class Records {
private Date startDate 
// getters and setters 
}
```

am trying to write query like below

```
String hql = "from Records where  DATE(startDate)=? ";
Query query = session.createQuery(hql);
query.setParameter(0, getStartDate());
```

Answer (score 0):

A number of things are not clear in your question. However, try adding TemporalType.DATE to your query, something like:

```
.. query.setParameter(0, getStartDate(), TemporalType.DATE);
```

Basically, JPA needs to know that you're filtering records using a Date field. If I may demo using a more elaborate example: if your entity class is Record and @Id is field startDate, then:

```
@Entity
@NamedQuery(name="Record.findByStartDate",
    query="SELECT e FROM Record e"   // here returning the whole entity
    + " WHERE e.startDate = :startDate")
@Table(name="records")
public class Record implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @Column(name="startDate")
    @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    private Date startDate;
    ...
}
```

And search query method would be like:

```
public Record findByStartDate (Date startDate) {
    try {
      return (Record) em.createNamedQuery("Record.findByStartDate")
        .setParameter("startDate", startDate, TemporalType.DATE)
        .getSingleResult();
    } catch (NoResultException e) {
        return null;
    }
  }
```

Comment: no i was not used temporal data type because i have to store date and time

Comment: 'Temporal' here is referring to time, not that the field is temporary.

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
  String hql = "from Records where  DATE(startDate)= DATE(:date) ";
        Query query = session.createQuery(hql);
        query.setParameter("date", new Date());
        System.out.println(query.list().size());
```